# Comparar Referer usando stripos()

Tags: php, referer

Hola me pregunto la manera de comparar el referer usando stripos() ejemplo:

```
<?php
//Verifica el referer
$mayreferr = @$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if(stripos($mayreferr,'misitio.mx')){}
```

El problema es que deseo usar una lista de sitios para comparar ejemplo:

> misitio1.com, misitio2.com, misitio3.com

Existe alguna manera ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver tu pregunta sin tener que hacer un arreglo, recorrerlo en un ciclo e ir preguntando por si existe esa subcadena en la url de referencia, encontré una solución un poco ortodoxa. Primero almacenas en un arreglo las direcciones que quieres comprobar que esten en tu **$mayreferr**, luego hice una función que lo que recive son 2 parámetros: el primero es la dirección donde va a buscar que existan las urls que ya conoces de antemano y el segundo parámetro son estas urls. Entonces siguiendo la idea en realidad en el cuerpo de esta función lo que haré será crear una variable donde reemplazare de la cadena original de la url cualquier ocurrencia de las direcciones del segundo parámetro por un espacio vacío y posteriormente compararé la longitud del parámetro 1 con la nueva cadena generada de esta sustitución, si ambas tienen la misma longitud es que no se hizo ningún cambio y por consiguiente no hay ninguna ocurrencia de estas urls en ese parámetro, de lo contrario si existia y devolveré true.

Acá esta el código:

```
$sitios = ['misitio.com','mysite.com'];

echo encontrar_url('http://www.mysite.com', $sitios) ? "Se encontro" : "No se encontro";

function encontrar_url($buscar, $urls){
    $str = str_replace($urls, [''], strtolower($buscar));
    $result = false;
    return !(strlen($str) === strlen($buscar));
}
```

Para aterrizar este ejemplo en tu caso quedaría de esta manera

```
$mayreferr = @$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$sitios = ['misitio1.com', 'misitio2.com', 'misitio3.com'];

if(encontrar_url($mayreferr, $sitios)){
    echo "Se encontro";
} else {
    echo "No se encontro";
}

function encontrar_url($buscar, $urls){
    $str = str_replace($urls, [''], strtolower($buscar));
    return !(strlen($str) === strlen($buscar));
}
```

Aclarar que si tus sitios van a ser como los que dejastes de ejemplo misitio1.com, misitio2.com, con una expresión regular resuelves tu problema, por tanto esta solución es más bien encaminada a urls diferentes no las que contienen una forma predeterminada. Espero que te sirva.

**EDIT** Le añadí strtolower a la variable **$buscar** para agregarle que no sea case sensitive, es decir sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta . lo que entiendo es que la function encontrar_url() Compara la longitud de la url no el nombre de la url . Si en dado caso se usa una url que no tenga el mismo nombre pero si la misma longitud igual quedaría como true?

Comment: El compara las urls pero luego de reemplazar las coincidencias con el arreglo que le provees, si ambas longitudes coinciden quiere decir que no hizo ningun reemplazo y por tanto no encontró esa dirección dentro del referer. Pruebalo con diferentes casos para que veas que funciona y se adapta a lo que quieres.

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona bien

Comment: Un placer. Saludos